# Keyboard Shortcut Working Only Once On Initialization?

Tags: java

I have the space bar set up to advance the "scene" of a game I am creating. The function is as follows (the Key Handler and everything are all properly implemented):

```
public void KeySPACE() {

beginGame(player, "Map0");

}
```

beginGame, for reference, looks like this:

```
public void beginGame (Player player, String map) {

player.createProfile();

this.map = mapFile.getMap(map);
this.map = findSpawnPoint();
this.arena = this.map.arena;

this.enemyPath = new EnemyPath(this.map);
this.scene = 1; //Game playing state
this.wave.waveNumber = 0;

}
```

My game starts at a menu screen, which you can advance to the game screen by pressing space (i.e. set scene = 1). However, I only want the space bar to do this once. The problem is, the user can inadvertently reset an active game by pressing the space bar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just add an if statement?

```
public void KeySPACE() {
    if(this.scene == 0){
        beginGame(player, "Map0");
    }
}
```

And just make sure that before the game starts, you are on scene 0.
Alternatively you can create a boolean value to do the same, for example:

```
public void KeySPACE() {
    if(!gameRunning) {
        beginGame(player, "Map0");
    }
}
```

You will need to define a boolean gameRunning which starts as false. You can set it to true in the beginGame method.

Comment: Bah, of course. I was hell bent on checking scene == 1. Not sure why. Thanks for pointing out my stupidity. :p

Comment: Sometimes it helps to take regular breaks :).